# Determine font of textbox and make contenteditable look the same as textbox

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, contenteditable

I am having trouble making a contenteditable look like a textbox on my site. Does anyone know what is the font on the picture - I have tried a lot of them an none matches well.
[image]

The contenteditable is above and the textarea is bellow .. i would like to know what is this font?

Here is the code as well

```css
#mw {
   -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    padding: 11px; 

}

.mw1 {
    padding: 11px; 

}
```

```html
<div id="mw" contenteditable>I am not really sure what this font is and I am trying to make a contenteditable area look like a text area. 

Thanks for the help.
</div>

<textarea id="aid" name="inputText" class="mw1">I am not really sure what this font is and I am trying to make a contenteditable area look like a text area. 

Thanks for the help.</textarea>
```

Comment: Got it it is :     font-family: Courier New;
    font-size:small;

Comment: But the problem is that font color isn't quite the same. In textarea it is a little bit bolder as in the picture. More bold that in the demo.

Comment: See my answer if you still have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still having trouble with trying to match fonts and color? See this Snippet for details.

### SNIPPET

```css
.textBox { font: 400 13px/1.428 'Courier New'; color: rgba(0,0,0,1); }
#textarea {
   -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    padding: 5px; 
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #ddd; 
    padding: 4;
   overflow: hidden; overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
   resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    width:300px;
    height: 100px;
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}

.maintextarea {
    padding: 5px; 
    border-radius: 4px;
    border:solid 2px #ddd;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;  
    width:300px;
    height: 100px;
    font: inherit;
    color:inherit;
}
```

```html
<section class="textBox">
<div id="textarea" contenteditable>
  In this demo, I have wrapped a &lt;section&gt; element around both boxes. It has a class name of .textBox.
  This is the CSS:
  .textBox { 
      font: 400 16px/1.428 'Courier New'; 
      color: rgba(57,64,68,1); 
  }
</div>

<textarea id="firsttextarea" name="inputText" cols="100" rows="20" class="maintextarea">
  Now for the 2 editors #textarea and .maintextarea we add the following CSS to both of them:
    font: inherit;
    color:inherit;
  </textarea>
  </section>
```

Comment: it is strange but color is only perfect when i specify color:black instead of color: rgba(0,0,0,1);  and make the font size 14 it is perfect.

Comment: That's great, happy coding. :-)

Answer (score 1):

i think the font is Consolas. but as for making the div appear like a textarea, you can try

```
<table bgcolor=buttonshadow cellpadding=3 cellspacing=3>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor=buttonhighlight>

      <div id="mw" style="
        font:consolas;
        width:400px;
        height:200px;
        overflow-y:scroll;
       overflow-x:hidden;" contenteditable>
       I am not really sure what this font is and I am trying to make a contenteditable area look like a text area. 

       Thanks for the help.
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Just adjust the Width and or Height to the way you like it.

This would work as long as you don't have a super long string fragment that has no spaces (ie a hyperlink). if you do then that super long word may be cut off.

You can remedy that by changing

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

to

```
overflow-x:auto;
```

but that would add a horizontal scroll bar if it is needed. Alternatively you can add a "-" and a space somewhere in the Long word to seperate it into two or more lines